# Angularjs : dom manipulation replacing and then reattaching to another parent with map

Tags: angularjs

> PROBLEM

I have a dom element, which i want to **detach it** from its parent and **append it** at some other location in the dom, angularjs way.

i could easily do this in jquery with detach and appendto, but i am unable, to find the same in angularjs way.

```
  var detached = jQuery('.toBeDetached');
  jQuery('.itemMaximixed').append(detached);
```

Note i need to detach since the element contains a **map** in it.

Comment: Can you give a little more context around the problem? It would have bindings? Do you expect the binding to continue to work? Is the movement inside a single controller html?

Comment: yes the movement is inside the single controller html ,, binding works ; BUT ng-change in select tag is not working

Answer (score 0):

It may not be applicable in your case, but you can use the `transclude` facility of an Angular directive to do this.

Comment: looking at the basic docs, i think that won't help here..Its basically meant to append and element inside the directive defn.  Do you have any idea about how transclude would fit in here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think attaching and deattaching would work. What I can suggest is destroying the recreating the template under different node.
You can use something like [ng-if](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angIf) in Angular 1.1.5 for this. Using multiple ng-if and associated conditions you can bind the same template at multiple location, which ever `ng-if` returns true that template would get loaded.

The template code can be duplicated or be out inside a ng-template script. Something like this

```
<div id='parent'>
   <div id='child1'>
     <div ng-if='condition1'><ng-include src='datatemplate' /></div>
   </div>
   <div id='child2'>
     <div ng-if='condition2'><ng-include src='datatemplate' /></div>
   </div>
</div>

<script id='datatemplate' type='text/ng-template'>
   <!-- Template HTML -->
</script>
```

Comment: templates won't work,, since i have a map state,, re-initalizing the tempalte would loose map data

Comment: For the same template same model should produce same HTML. You reinit with same model

Comment: what about maps,, reinit will break the state

Comment: That depends upon how map has been implemented. If the map gets the same data it should restore its state. When you talk about map is it something like Google Maps?